# Polyhedra collapses

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry

I wanted to ask how to understand what a 2-polyhedron is and what the Collapsibility of Zeemans Conjecture $K \times I$ means in a geometric sense? How do I visualize the collapse? Or where can I find good books on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with these notes?

> Alexander Kupers, "Zeeman's Conjecture," 2017.
> [PDF download](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ekupers/notes/zeemansconjecture.pdf).

[image: Fig4]

Kupers refers to this as "a good reference":

> Sergei Matveev and Dale Rolfsen,
> "Zeeman’s collapsing conjecture," *Two-dimensional homotopy and
> combinatorial group theory*, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., vol. 197, Cambridge Univ. Press,
> Cambridge, 1993.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I get it right a 2-polyhedron is in fact just a 2 dimensional simplicial complex and collapsing this 2-polyhedron $K$ with $K \times I$ means in fact that it is "expanded" to a 3 dimensional object and then collapses to a point?

Comment: @LogicTheorist Lure gives a nice and short account here of the polyhedron category :https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture2.pdf The main point being that a finite polyhedron is essentially the realization of a finite simplicial complex. It does not have a distinguished triangulation, but rather a class of them.